# std::async and std::shared_future causes the program to fall

Tags: c++, asynchronous, stl, future, void

I am trying to run some function in asynchronous manner. For this purpose I wrote class called `Core` where I use `std::async` to run function in different thread and `std::shared_future<int>` to wait for this thread and possibly to get future result. This is code of **test program:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

class Core : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Core>
{
public:
    Core()
        : isRunning_(false) {
    };
    ~Core() {
        isRunning_ = false;
        if (f_.valid())
        {
            f_.wait();
            std::cout << "Result is: " << f_.get() << std::endl;
        }
    };
    void Start() {
        isRunning_ = true;
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        f_ = std::async(std::launch::async, [self, this]() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    if (!isRunning_)
                        break;

                    std::cout << "Boom" << std::endl; // Error occurs here
                    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
                }
            }
            catch (const std::exception& e) {
                std::cerr << "Loop error:" << e.what();
            }
            return 999;
        });
    }

private:
    std::shared_future<int> f_;
    std::atomic<bool> isRunning_;
};

int main()
{
    try {
        std::shared_ptr<Core> load(new Core);
        load->Start();

        throw std::runtime_error("Generate error"); // Added in order to generate error
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "Error occurred: " << e.what();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Each time when I start this program it crashes at this line:

```
std::cout << "Boom" << std::endl; // Error occurs here
```

with this error:

[image: Error output]

That is debugger error and call stack which I managed to get during debugging:

[image]

*Looks like `Core` destructor function doesn't call at all. Why is it happens? weird!!!*

Could you tell me where is my mistake? Thanks.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: There is no error description... program just stops immediately

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I know but debugger did not give me answer for my question.

Comment: `throw std::runtime_error("Error");`???

Comment: "program just stops immediately" this is perfectly legal, on all common OSes detached threads will be killed when the process dies .. what do you expect to happen ? do you want some output to be displayed ? try adding a this_thread::sleep_for... before main end

Comment: BTW, "void main" hurts my sensibility !

Comment: Reposting my answer as a comment: The program does produce an output when compiled on gcc. Try adding a getchar() at the end of the main function. What is probably happening is that your main thread is quitting too soon.

Comment: Just to clarify @NathanOliver's comment, I am not saying the screen is closing, just that the async thread doesn't get to execute, because the main thread quits.

Comment: @TobySpeight Question was edited to show what kind of debugging I have done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When main thread returns from main() it starts tearing down the environment before terminating the whole process. All this while background thread is accessing objects there are being destroyed or have been destroyed already.

I am not sure what you are triying to achieve, but you are doing something wrong:

- Your lambda should execute some work and return immediately after it is done e.g. you should never loop forever.
- Your main thread should wait for your future to complete by calling `std::future<T>::get()`.

Comment: But I am waiting for future in `Core` destructor and it is prevent `Core` object to be destroyed before loop exit.

Comment: I see. The problem is that when your thread exits try-catch block it destroys shared pointer to `Core` instance, background thread still maintains reference to it, so its destructor is never called and never will be called. You gave that pointer to a background thread when you did `[self, this]`.

Comment: Yes, and you give this shared pointer to a background thread. And a main thread also has a pointer to it, so in total you have 2 pointers to it - you can check this by calling `std::shared_ptr<Core>::count()`. When main thread exits, there is 1 pointer remaining that still keeps `Core` alive.

Comment: So, `Core` object alive. Why program crashes?

Comment: As I explained, main thread exits and tears down the environment. Looks it is able to destroy standard locale object when your background thread tries to access it by writing to `std::cout`. You are writing to a dead stream, basically. Never let any background threads do any work when you are returning from main or calling `exit`.

Comment: Looks like we need to explicitly destroy `Core` object (add `Stop` function)  in main thread and all derived threads when we leave `main` function. This will be solution.